# perl Use of uninitialized value $_ in string eq

Tags: arrays, perl, initialization, equals, dereference

Why i have sometimes this error?
    Use of uninitialized value $_ in string eq

```
if (defined($infos->{"valeur_exclude"}) &&
grep { $number eq $_ } @{$infos->{"valeur_exclude"}});
```

Thanks

Comment: This means the variable `$_` has no value (its value is the special value `undef`). Either it never got a value, or at some point `undef` was assigned to it.

Answer (score 5):

The array contains `undef` somewhere. Check for `defined` before comparing:

```
grep { defined && $number eq $_ }
```

Answer (score -4):

Maybe, regexp instead EQ?

my @foo = grep {!/^#/} @bar;

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html

Comment: What question are you answering?